# Map() function not giving expected results Google script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, map-function

I am trying to learn how to use Map(), in the function below Method1, the function runs i.e it executes and does not throw an error but it does not change any cell values equal to `Networking - 1` to `1` it leaves the data unchanged

I am not understanding what is not working.

```
function Method1() {
  var ss     = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
  var sheet  = ss.getSheetByName('Elements');  
  var rng    = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = rng.getValues();
  
  values = values.map(x => {return x = (x=="Networking - 1" ) ? 1: x;});

  sheet.getRange(1,1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Issue / Explanation:

- The issue is that `values` is a `2D` array and when you are using a single map
  `x` represents a **row**. You can't compare a row with a single
  value. It wouldn't make sense to compare something like `['','','']` with `''`. Therefore, you need to find a way to get every element of this array and compare that against the string value.
- My approach would be to use **a map inside of another map** function. The first map will get the **rows** and the second one the **elements** of each row and compare them against the string:

  ```
  values = values.map(x => x.map(y=>y=="Networking - 1"  ? 1: y))
  ```

  `x` will be the row and `y` will be an element in that row. In this way you compare an element with a single value `"Networking - 1"`.
- When you use a single line in `map` and in other similar array functions you don't need to use `return` and `{}`. Also you want to return the returned value, not the assignment operation.

### **Solution:**

```
function Method1() {
  var ss     = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
  var sheet  = ss.getSheetByName('Elements');  
  var rng    = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = rng.getValues();
  values = values.map(x => x.map(y=>y=="Networking - 1"  ? 1: y))
                      
  sheet.getRange(1,1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```